# Formatting a string from a list of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a list of integers `l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` and I want to print them in a formatted way as such:

`[1,2] [3,4] [5,6]`

How can I get this result in an easy way? I've tried using:

```
print("[%d, %d] [%d, %d] [%d, %d]" % l)
```

But it didn't work since `l` is not a number. Any pointers on how this effect can be achieved would be appreciated.

I know I can use

```
  print("[", l[0], "," ,1[1] ...
```

But that is way to ugly and ineffective to write code, and was hoping for a better way.

Comment: You could print three separate list slices: `print("%s %s %s" % (l[:2], l[2:4], l[4:]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of elements is fixed, we can try this:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print('[{}, {}] [{}, {}] [{}, {}]'.format(*lst))

=> '[1, 2] [3, 4] [5, 6]'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
print(*map(list, zip(l[::2], l[1::2])))
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2] [3, 4] [5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group the list items in pairs by creating an iterator from the list and zipping the iterator with itself:

```
i = iter(l)
print(*map(list, zip(i, i)))
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 2] [3, 4] [5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
evens = [i for i in l if i % 2 == 0]
odds = [i for i in l if i % 2 != 0]

zip(evens, odds)
```

Comment: I think the pattern is each successive pair of elements, regardless of their value.

Answer (score 0):

or this

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

print( *[ (l[2*i], l[2*i+1] ) for i in range(0,len(l)//2)])
```

produces
`[1, 2] [3, 4] [5, 6]`